# Datastudio Community Connector - Add filter

Tags: looker-studio

I have a site with hundreds of members who would like to see activity relating to their products. We use datastudio at the moment, creating a report manually for a few who have asked.

We would like to be able to send out a single report that grabs the member details from the url and sets the report to that member. We followed the datastudio docs https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials but it's not very clear

```
function getAuthType() {
  var response = { type: 'NONE' };
  return response;
}

function getConfig(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var config = cc.getConfig();

  config
      .newTextInput()
      .setId('token')
      .setName('Enter user token')
      .setAllowOverride(true);

  config.setDateRangeRequired(false);
  config.setIsSteppedConfig(false);

  return config.build();
}

function getFields(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;


  fields.newDimension()
    .setId('tokenValue')
    .setType(types.TEXT);

  return fields;
}

function getSchema(request) {
  var fields = getFields(request).build();
  return { schema: fields };
}

function getData(request) {
  var token = request.configParams.token;

}
```

Has anyone set up a community connector that would allow multiple users to see a single report but only see what's specific to them?

I'm not sure if the token is being set property. It displays as the placeholder only. Is there a way to be sure what value my parameter is assigned?

[image]

We haven't got the the point of passing a url parameter. What we would like to do is pass the token value (Member details) to an existing filter. Is this possible in a community connector?

Comment: Are your users going to be logged into their Google account?

Comment: Yes they would be logged in via their own account. And we have given everyone access to view and edit whilst testing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Filter by email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766) feature to filter your data based on the viewer's email address. This works out of the box and won't require you to build a custom connector.

Alternatively, if you do want to build a custom connector, follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/row-level-filtering) that seems more suitable for your use case.